# Are there any real life situations where declaring all floating point literals as double causes real problems in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, literals

Meaning, in a "normal" situation where the performance loss of type promotion is irrelevant, where nobody checks for equality on a float and where nobody declares anything funny like

```
void f(float x) {/*do something*/};
void f(double x) {/*do something completely different*/};
```

and so on.

I am aware that the general question of "C++ f suffix why?" has been asked a thousand times, but all the answers always are about technical details and contrived examples. I haven't found any satisfactory answer that shows an actually relevant situation, where the distinction is important.

Comment: " has been asked a thousand times, but all the answers always are about technical details and contrived examples." so you are asking the same question, but adding the premise that you arent interested in existing answers, because you think they are too "contrived" ?!?

Comment: Are you asking for historical examples of system errors? Something in the news? That's a valid question, I just want to make sure. Anything I give you will be contrived otherwise by definition.

Comment: @idclev463035818: OP is not excluding overloads *per se* but is saying there are no overloads such that some `void f(float x)` calculates an orbital path for the space shuttle and `void f(double x)` orders food delivery. That is, all overloads of analogous types perform analogous functions.

Comment: `float f = some_decimal_written_as_double;` incurs 2 rounding: text to `double` and `double` to `float`.  Once in a while (about 1 in a million) and depending on the compiler, that differs from `float f = some_decimal_written_as_float;`

Comment: @EricPospishil thanks, I really didn't get it, was a bit confused by the wording of the question. Excluding such overloads can be considered "normal", I agree

Comment: @JohnFilleau I don't mean contrived in the technical sense of made up, but rather in the sense that a given example is either not something you will encounter in real code, or the problem caused is not relevant in a real context. And yes a historical example would be appreciated, though is not necessarily what I am asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a good "real-life" example at hand. Instead I want to try to convince you with a hopefully simple example.

Lets assume all function with overloads for `float` and `double` do "the right thing":

```
void f(float x) {/*do something*/};
void f(double x) {/*do the same thing*/};
```

Moreover, when only one of the overloads is available, we can call it with a literal of either type:

```
void f_float(float x) {/*do something*/};
void f_double(double x) {/*do the same thing*/};
f_float(3.0);    // ok
f_float(3.0f);   // ok
f_double(3.0);   // ok
f_double(3.0f);  // ok
```

`float`s convert to `double`s and vice versa.

---

If all code is fine with either `float` or `double`, this is end of story. However, you don't need to do something "funny" to get the code to break.

---

> I haven't found any satisfactory answer that shows an actually relevant situation, where the distinction is important.

The distinction is important when the type of the literal is used to infer the type of something else. Being able to convert between `double` and `float` is not all you need to be able to replace any `float` literal with a `double` literal without breaking code.

In the above example `f_float` can be called with either `3.0` or `3.0f`. Now suppose you have a function that only accepts a `std::vector<float>`:

```
void bar(const std::vector<float>& x){}
```

and something that given a single value, constructs a vector:

```
template <typename T>    
std::vector<T> make_vect(const T& t){ return {T{}}; }
```

Then the type of the literal makes the code either fail or pass:

```
bar(make_vect(0.3f));
//bar(x.make_vect(0.3)); // ERROR
```

[Complete Example](https://godbolt.org/z/PKGGG6).

*TL;DR*
The whole point is just that you can convert between `float` and `double`, but in general there is no conversion available between `some_template<float>` and `some_template<double>`. The type of a literal can be relevant, even though you don't mind conversions between `float` and `double`. Changing a `3.0f` to a `3.0` can make code break, that was fine otherwise

Comment: The case with templates is good. Though in that situation, the compiler would refuse to compile, right? I am wondering whether there is a situation where the code would compile, but result in unintended behaviour at runtime.

Comment: @Garbaz "fail to compile" can be easily turned into "do the uninteded" via SFINAE or similar. It would just make the example more compilcated, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Garbaz my point was just that changing the literal can potentially break code at some completely different place. In the example it is obvious what is breaking and why, but consider that  the distance between the literal and the function that only accepts `float` can be large